# jQuery are any children focused

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to use jQuery to determine if any (not all) children `li` within a `ul` are focused, and if not then trigger the rest of the script. The code i used have started as:

```
 if($('ul').children('li').is(":focus"))  {
  // do nothing {
 else {
  // do script
 }
```

and

```
if($('ul li:focus').length == 0 ) {
  // do script
}
```

and

```
if(!($('ul li').is(":focus"))) {
  // do script
}
```

All without success, either nothing happens or it only works with the first `li`. I've used console log and it seems these if statements are all passing as true, the script within is supposed to remove the class from the parent ul, along the lines of:

```
 $(this).parent().removeClass('classname');
```

Before the `if statement` i determine if any of the list elements are `blurred`, which all comes together as (replace the `if statement` with all those above):

```
var navItem = $('.class li ul');
navItem.on('blur', 'li', function() {  
  console.log("blur fired");
  if (!($(this).parent.find('li').is(":focus"))) {
     console.log("No focus on li children fired");
     $(this).parent().removeClass('classname');
  }
});
```

unfortunately this is on a limited platform so my capabilities are limited, though I expect jQuery to not be restricted by these limitations, just dynamic html elements.

**UPDATE**

I have made all list elements have `tabindex` of 1 via:

```
navItem.find('li').attr("tabindex", "1");
```

Currently what happens is if i tab through the dropdown after the first list element is blurred the navigation disappears (class is removed from parent `ul`), however it continues navigating through the list (as it is offcanvas, not `display: none` which is the way it was made by the platform theme dev) firing both `console.log` events each time an item is tabbed to.

Comment: Not sure, but... can li element have focus at all? Quote: " The focus event is sent to an element when it gains focus. This event is implicitly applicable to a limited set of elements, such as form elements (<input>, <select>, etc.) and links (<a href>). In recent browser versions, the event can be extended to include all element types by explicitly setting the element's tabindex property."  https://api.jquery.com/focus/

Comment: Can you explain what the goal of your code is, because I'm sure there's better ways to do it.

Comment: @nevermind while that is true, the purpose of this is accessibility, though admittedly I haven't set the tabindex yet, perhaps that would be the solution lol, let me try.

Comment: that and only one element can ever have focus.  [According to MDN you can also check `document.activeElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/activeElement)

Comment: @RalfD'hooge i fail to see how it'd be a duplicate, that is a general question about what can be focused, mine is how to determine if a non-natively focusable element can be blurred in jquery.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, accessibility, more specifically keyboard accessible navigation and the better way would be to modify the html elements not using jquery i think but due to limitations of this specific platform that is, unfortunately and to my displeasure, not the case.

Comment: @Nathan I just would suggest, if all conditions are done to be able to focus the listitem

Comment: @RalfD'hooge I don't follow, can you clarify please

Answer (score 0):

As you may have noticed, the :focus event is not triggered in the `LI` element, it only triggers for `<A>nchor` elements that have a `href` property. So, to achieve your desired behaviour, I suggest to add anchors inside your `LI` elements and check for its `focus`.

Follows the solution for your problem: [Solution](http://codepen.io/RKTI/pen/LNKLPj)

HTML

```
<ul>
<li>
  <a href="#">1</a>
  <ul>
    <li>
        <a href="#">1.1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">1.2</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
li { border: 1px solid #000; }
li a:focus { background-color: #F00;display:block; }
```

JQUERY

```
(function(){ 

    $('body').on('keyup', checkFocused)        

    function checkFocused() {
        console.log($('ul li a:focus').text())
    }   

})()
```

Comment: thanks for this; i did change it to anchor tags, however what is failing is the `if statement` which keeps triggering as true, so the trick here i think is to accurately determine if none of the elements within the `ul` are focused (now that ive changed it to focus the `a` tags within the `li`s i guess it's if none of the `a`s within the `ul` are targeted) and if none are then i can execute from there

Comment: you should trigger your test inside a keyup event, so you will have sure that the link is focused by tabbing. 

onkeyup do your test for "length" `$('ul li a:focus').length`

Comment: I've done that, the `if statement` always returns true. I've just started using `.each()` as well, nothing is working by saying if ALL are false then xyz, or if one of all is true then do nothing, etc.